# Add line numbers to Microsoft Report Builder output

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012, builder

I have a report made by Microsoft Report Builder and I need to add line numbers. When the data is represented as a table, this is easy to accomplish by adding a new column for the line number. However, when the data is a text block inside a text block, there is no way to add numbers to each line of text. I have thought of exporting the report to word, reading the word doc into python, and adding lines there,  but at first attempt it seems a little difficult. Has anyone had to do this before?

Comment: why not calculate the row_number in your dataset and simply display it on your report.. like any other column?

Comment: I think more info is required...What will determine a line? Are there carriage returns/ line feeds in the text or is it just word wrapped text? If there are not characters to determine the end of a line, are you using a fixed font, will the report width always be fixed etc?  I think this might be possible but it will not be simple. so if you have an idea that you know will work via Python, you might want to go that route.